# Dual Boot won't show

Tags: 14.04

I have been trying for days now to get Ubuntu to dual boot with Windows 10, I have it installed but won't show at all looks like it's invisible.

Comment: Please add details in your question. What do you mean by 'invisible'? Did you installed Ubuntu successfully? Does your system boots into Windows? Do you get to select the OS you want to boot into shortly after you power on your system?

Comment: What brand/model system? What video card/chip. Some need boot parameters if nVidia or AMD video. If newer computer better to use 16.04 as it is more current. 
May be best to see details, you can run from your Ubuntu live installer or any working install, use ppa version not older Boot-Repair ISO:
Post the link to the Create BootInfo summary report. Is part of Boot-Repair:
https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Boot-Info and:
https://sourceforge.net/p/boot-repair/home/Home/

Answer (score -1):

Depends a lot how your windows is set up to boot, and whether you are using windows' boot loader or GRUB bootloader in MBR.

Here's one way to do dualboot, (even) if Windows is running on a bitlocker-encrypted drive:
https://confluence.csc.fi/display/ATUKI/2016/08/05/Dual-booting+Bitlocker+Windows+7+and+Ubuntu+16.04+with+NeoGRUB+and+EasyBCD

Steps to create the dualboot:

1. Shrink the existing NTFS partition to make room for the Ubuntu
   installation. Rightclick Computer - Manage - Disk Management -
   rightclick partition - Shrink Volume. About 20-30GB should do.
2. Pause bitlocker while the configuration is being updated. Control panel - Bitlocker Drive Encryption - Suspend Protection
3. Create a Live-USB of the Ubuntu or whatever Linux you're about to install. Used LiLi myself.
4. Boot the computer with the Live USB stick, Install Ubuntu with advanced settings.
5. Add two logical partitions to the empty space: a swap partition the same size as the machines RAM, and an ext4 partition with mountpoint / (root)
           Make sure to set the bootloader to the logical partition, not MBR. Example: /dev/sda6 instead of /dev/sda
6. After Ubuntu has finished installing, boot to windows and download EasyBCD
7. Reveal the unencrypted windows partition from Computer - Manage - Disk Management - rightclick system partition - Change drive letter and paths. I assigned the letter Q: for the system drive.
8. Using EasyBCD, Add a new entry to the bootmenu from the NeoGRUB tab (install)
9. Click configure on the NeoGRUB tab and write this entry, referencing /dev/sda6:

   > ```
   > title Ubuntu
   > root (hd0,5)
   > chainloader (hd0,5)+1
   > ```
10. Save changes from the Edit boot menu -tab
11. Boot, verify that both Windows and Ubuntu start, resume bitlocker protection

Comment: *whether you are using windows' boot loader or GRUB bootloader in MBR*... No, it's always Grub. Windows cannot boot anything but other Windows versions. The difference is between Legacy/CSM (BIOS) where Grub is installed in the MBR thus replacing whatever was there before, and UEFI where Grub is installed in the EFI partition, alongside all the other boot entries (EFI files).

Comment: Instruction mentioning "Windows 7" are typically for Legacy/CSM. Considering all your answer is predicated in this most likely wrong assumption, all of it is wrong and outdated, hence the -1.

Comment: My method leaves the MBR in windows' hands, and puts grub on the beginning of the linux boot partition. EasyBCD uses Grub4DOS to divert the boot from windows to the grub partition. It still works with windows 10.